# Swift Array[UInt8] using Bitwise operator not work?

Tags: arrays, swift, bitwise-operators

I got confused when testing my code on playground

```
var test: [UInt8] = [5, 6, 7, 8]

print(test[0]) -> 5

print(5<<8) -> 1280

print(test[0]<<8) -> error
```

[image]

The error turns out to be like above

Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the bitwise shift operators, you must shift by *less than* the type size of the value to shift, in bits. In this case, you're trying to shift a `UInt8` by 8 bits – which is out of that range.

The reason it's working for `print(5<<8) -> 1280` is because Swift is inferring those types to be of `Int` – and therefore it'll be either 32 or 64 bit, depending on the platform. Because 8 is less than this, it will work.

If you explicitly cast the `5` to `UInt8`, you'll get a *compiler* error saying:

> Shift amount is greater than or equal to type size in bits

However, it appears Swift is unable to provide the same compiler error for arrays – only a runtime one.

The solution therefore is to work with larger types. Depending on what you're using this code for, you may want to use a `UInt16` array.

```
var test: [UInt16] = [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Or you if you're using the shifted values independently of the array, you can just cast them to a larger type before shifting:

```
print(UInt16(test[0])<<8)
```

Although you should note that [Apple recommends you use `Int`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID317) for integer types, even if your values are known to be non-negative – unless you specifically need to work with types of a fixed size.

Comment: @HungCLo Happy to help :)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot shift a UInt8 by 8 or more bits. If you check the console you'll find the Swift runtime is telling you that.

```
fatal error: shift amount is larger than type size in bits
```

The reason `5 << 8` works is because `5` is an `Int` which is usually 32 or 64 bits in size.

If you want a larger integer output, cast the value before doing the shift:

```
print(UInt32(test[0]) << 8)
//    ^^^^^^
```